# Angular 2's Syntax Changes - Any Reason?

Tags: angular

I was looking over some of the syntax coming up in Angular 2 [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/directives/). I'm curious, what are the reasons for some of the changes?

Specifically This: `<input ng-model="mymodel.name' />` to `<input [(ng-model)]="mymodel.name" />`

Or This: `<div ng-class="{ 'padding': mymodel.name.length != 0}">` to `<div [ngStyle]="{ 'padding': mymodel.name.length != 0}">`

Or This: `<button ng-click="mymodel.foo()">` to `<button (click)="mymodel.foo()">`

Comment: You will get to know by the end of this year :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource I've seen for this is Miško Hevery's ng-conf 2015 talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dMBcqwvYA0

Slides for the talk: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1XoizA8Dm_S3SU1jYPERmgWVIbqjGOXolpF3Jm2b8xKA

Miško is the creator of Angular.

In brief (very brief, you really should watch this video for a great overview of Angular 2 concepts, especially if you have an Angular 1 background):

- the newer syntax is less ambiguous, hence editors can now perform static syntax checking
- DOM property binding is, in many ways, better than HTML attribute binding (the brackets signify property binding)
- event binding now uses parenthesis, rather than requiring special ng-* directives for each type of event

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad, I'm quite aware of the disadvantages of link rot.  In this case, however, the answer really requires a good 20 minutes of lecture, and if people really want to understand the (multiple) reasons for the multiple syntax changes, they really need to watch the Misko talk.  (Also, I doubt it will get deleted from YouTube anytime soon -- i.e., anytime in the next few years.)

Comment: @Mogsdad, see if you like my updates.  I do aim to please :)

Comment: To future reviewers, this is not _link only_ after edits. Just because it has couple links in it, don't jump to the _recommend deletion_.